# Personal PyPI package: can't import subpackages

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pypi

I've turned my personal utility functions into a package to be able to use it across all my projects. As such, I've re-structured the repo, published it on [GitHub](https://github.com/Jordan-Kowal/jklib/tree/master/jklib), and packaged it for [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/jklib/).

However, I can't get it to work. I've installed it using `pip install jklib`, **but I can't import the subpackages**. For example, I get the error `No module named 'jklib.django'`

I've tried changing the content of all the `__init__.py` files with no success. I've already uploaded PyPI packages before successfully, though they didn't have subpackages.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `packages=setuptools.find_packages()` in your `setup.py` to include all subpackages. There is only `__init__.py` in `site_packages/jklib/` when installed if use `packages=["jklib"]`.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a shot

Comment: Worked like a charm. I thought that simply declaring "jklib" would be enough as it would automatically detect nested packages, but I guess not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still interesting.
I own a function collection too on Github called [ofunctions](https://github.com/netinvent/ofunctions), and have created a "namespace" package which will install everything, and subpackages which will only install the necessary functions, including its dependencies.

I've managed to create a single `setup.py` file which deals with the pacakge itself, and all subpackages and requirements.
In the end, I wanted to achieve the following install syntax to install just a part of the pacakge:

```
pip install ofunctions.network
```

Or the whole pacakge via

```
pip install ofunctions
```

Have a look at my git repo construction if it helps.
Best regards.